# How to open unicode file name in Dired mode in Emacs

Tags: unicode, emacs, dired

For normal file names, we can use ! (shell command) to open files in Dired mode in Emacs (newest version in MS Windows), but when unicode file names are met, it reports error that

> "[file_name]" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Works for me with Emacs v25.1.1 on Linux. Please paste the file name you're trying here.

Comment: It is interesting. I created a new file with unicode name and found it working in Emacs. Then I renamed the file with the same name, and it is working in Emacs now. Thanks!